# How do I pass an authorization header in ASIHTTPRequest?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, http-headers, nsurlconnection, asihttprequest

I am trying to do the following:

```
curl -H "authorization: 49a74aebda84ffe1f7ebe25cb2c5e3fa1013dd76" -X GET http://mywebsite.com/api/v1/tags
```

Here is my code:

```
   dataRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [dataRequest setDelegate:self];
    [dataRequest setRequestMethod:@"GET"];
    [dataRequest addRequestHeader:@"Authorization" value:api_key];
    [dataRequest setPostValue:url forKey:@"url"];
    [dataRequest startAsynchronous];
```

I am not getting a valid JSON back, and want to make sure I am sending the request properly. I have ensured that the api_key and url are valid.

Comment: Slightly off topic, note that ASIHTTPRequest is not actively developed anymore, as stated [here](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) at the top of the page.

Comment: What does mean api_key here. Can you explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code example should not be using `ASIFormDataRequest`. It should use `ASIHTTPRequest`.

```
dataRequest = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[dataRequest setDelegate:self];
[dataRequest addRequestHeader:@"Authorization" value:api_key];
[dataRequest startAsynchronous];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
dataRequest = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

[dataRequest setDelegate:self];

[dataRequest addRequestHeader:@"Authorization" value:api_key];

[dataRequest startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: Code dumps are not answers.  Please edit your answer and explain what this code is, how it works, and how it answers the question.

Comment: @Charles- i know . no need of your suggestion